# Tweepy auto run

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Can some help me understand why when I run this code once it is done it doesn't continue to loop? I want it to run every 12 hrs or so.

```
def searchBot():
    for tweet in tweets:
        try:
            tweet.retweet()
            tweet.favorite()
            print ("Done")
            time.sleep(5)
        except tweepy.TweepError as e:
            print (e.reason)
            time.sleep(5)
while True:
    searchBot()
    time.sleep(11)
```

Comment: Where are you running it? what errors are you seeing?

Comment: I’m running on the vs code terminal and I don’t get any errors.